# Set marker in the centre of the polygon in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, gis

How can I place the icon marker in the centre of a polygon?

```
const geoJson = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {},
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -1.127471923828125,
              52.347504844796546
            ],
            [
              -1.130218505859375,
              52.34456858538671
            ],
            [
              -1.1446380615234375,
              52.343939361569554
            ],
            [
              -1.1391448974609375,
              52.33261180150486
            ],
            [
              -1.1188888549804688,
              52.33114320164082
            ],
            [
              -1.1079025268554688,
              52.331772607553205
            ],
            [
              -1.1085891723632812,
              52.343519874049804
            ],
            [
              -1.127471923828125,
              52.347504844796546
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```